# Can I include a use case multiple times.. true?

Tags: include, uml, use-case, staruml

[image: -------]

Is my work right? the include many time can be a probleme where ? and how i fix it  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML allows a use case to be included by any number of other use cases (including 0).

But in your diagram none of your includes are valid.

`UC1 - - - -<<include>> - - ->UC2` means **each time** *UC1* is executed then *UC2* is executed too, and this is not the case for you :

- very probably to search a company can be done alone, without having to search for a product too
- it is not needed to accept the localisation when searching for a product. May be for a delivery but not for a search
- to accept the localisation cannot ask for the authentication *each time*,  probably the authentication is a precondition of several use cases but it must be done *one* time
- to see the localisation on the map cannot request the permission *each time*, the permission is a precondition and if needed it must be done *one* time

You have to look at the extension

Comment: I would also prefer extend over include in this case. I do not agree with Bruno's statement that 'UC1 includes UC2' means that UC2 is executed always when UC1 is executed. I would define this relationship as follows: "The included UseCase must be available for the behavior of the including UseCase to be completely described." (quoted from the UML spec).

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl In [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) the definition of the include between UC is `An Include relationship specifies that a UseCase contains the behavior defined in another UseCase` . The sentence `The included UseCase must be available for the behavior of
the including UseCase to be completely described` is a constraint, it is not the definition. Definitively `UC1 - - -<<include>> - -> UC2` means *UC2* is executed when *UC1* is, you confuse include and extend.

Comment: I think both sentences are part of the definition. Anyway, they don't imply that UC2 is executed always for every possible scenario. Suppose UC2 is included at step 3 of the basic flow of UC1. Then, I think it is allowed to have an alternative flow of UC1 which executes only step 1 and then follows alternative steps, not including UC2.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl again you confuse with extend being conditional thanks to extension point

Comment: No, I know what I'm talking about. I know that some text books agree with you, but it is not what the UML specification says.